# CF9 not showing richtext editor on one server but works on another

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor

We have two identical installations of CF9 (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/cfide/...) using the FCKeditor. One is the staging and the other the production server. On the staging server the editor shows the rich text but on the production server only the standard textarea field without the rich text controls. The CF files are identical. Also a third server works just fine. All 3 servers are CF 9.0.1 64 bit win 2008.

Comment: Since this is a server configuration issue, would it be better off at [sf]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS or Apache ( your webserver ) do you have the virtual directory to CFIDE ( alias in Apache ) pointing to the actual CFIDE directory on disk?

Comment: You are the best :) It happened automatically with all servers but this one. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Just as a point of order. You really shouldn't have cfide mapped on production servers. It's a security risk to do that. If you need the components like the text area, then I would recommend only mapping the cfide/scripts folder in your chosen webserver.

Comment: @Axel: If this answer solved your problem, you should mark it _accepted_ by clicking the checkbox to the left. (See also: [faq#howtoask])